# vscode: Is it possible to import some files by deault for syntax highlighting purpose

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm using Vscode with Pylance
I have many files that have reportUndefined variable warnings, the files individually don't have the imports that would define variables reported as the missing.
But the imports and individual files are added into single file later, so it is not a problem when the program is executed.

For example following files,

```
importfile.py
file1.py
file2.py
```

are combined into single file in essence.

Is it possible to import some files globally and would re-import on any changes to the files.

Comment: _But the imports and individual files are added into single file later_ <--- Can you explain what that means in more detail?

Comment: @kanna -What does "import certain files through deault to highlight syntax" mean? Do you want to resolve the "reportUndefined variable" warning?

Comment: Yes, I would like to resolve `reportUndefined variable` warning. If it is possible to load some files as part of syntax checker, for example if `importfile.py` is loaded, there should not be these warnings in `file1.py` and `filel2.py`

Answer (score 0):

In VSCode, when importing a file, the imported file will be used as a module, and VSCode will start from the parent folder of the currently opened file when searching for the file. Therefore, the location of the folder where the file is located will affect the VSCode Find, and Pylance as an extension to provide related functions, it will display related warnings.

Usually, although the terminal will display the warning "`reportUndefinedVariable`", this does not affect the execution of the code. Therefore, we can use the following settings to close it:

[image]

Or add the following settings to "`settings.json`":

> ```
> "python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
>       "reportUndefinedVariable": "none"
>     },
> ```